# copying files with same names

Tags: files, cp

I have directories

```
--dir1
    image1
    image2
    image3
--dir2
    image1
    image2
    image3
--dir3
    image1
    image2
    image3
```

I want to copy all the files (that have the same names) from all the directories into a new directory with new names and number them from 1 to last in order...

How may I do this?

The files are images scanned from old film that I need in order to add them into a digital film. There are thousands of them...

Comment: Have you actually tried anything on your own?

Comment: Not much. Thats why i asked. Do you have a solution ?

Comment: Given the nine files in your example, what would these files be called after renaming them?

Comment: Do you really want to order from `1`, or would you prefer zero left-padded (`000001`) so that the default sorting order is easier

Comment: They can be called whatever just so I have them in order.  And yes 000001 would be just fine.  Oh, and the example is just to show what it looks like, there are hundreds of folders and thousands of images.

Comment: Do you want `copy` - or `move`?

Comment: I actually want to move them. I just thought it might be safer to copy them first. But I could go for moving them also.

Comment: If you aren't even going to even make an effort to do this, then why do you expect people on the internet to do it for you? With the amount of data that you're dealing with, you're going to need to know how whatever tool that you use operates and might operate if there is any data that might have special characters, etc. You could have done research on your own and resolved this by now rather than waiting for someone to give something that you wouldn't even understand.

Comment: What ?  There are friendly ppl on the internet helping ppl in all ways possible. That's what they do, myself also. And it feel really good to be able to help when you can. You should try it.

Comment: @HenrikKjellHolmqvist, if you check the Q/A you will see we try to help a lot. But w/o any try from OP looks like misuse of our work. So if you want help show some effort.

Comment: What is this ? what am i missing ? I thought this was a place to get help from volunteers. I dont even know what an OP is. how am i misusing your work ?

Comment: @HenrikKjellHolmqvist, OP = Original Poster, in this case you. And this is not a scripting service, this is a place where you have PROBLEM (with your code, configuration, etc.) and search for support.

Comment: If a file does _not_ have the same name as another file, would that be copied or not? For example, if there was an `image4` file in one of the directories in your example.  Could you possibly just tell us what the shown names would be renamed as?

Comment: Ok, maybe I am in the wrong place. I'm sorry for that.

Comment: @Kusalananda♦. Yes I would like to copy/move all files in all directories. Say I want to empty the first dir move or copy the files to say FILMDIR and rename them from 00001.jog 00002.jpg and so on and then I want to move to the next dir and empty that into my FILMDIR continuing the counting from the last .jog  in FILMDIR.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `bash` shell to copy the files to the directory `destdir` with new names on the format `nnnnnn.jpg` where `n` is some digit.

We assume that all files that we want to copy are matched by the single globbing pattern `dir*/image*`, as they would be given your example.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

num=0
mkdir -p destdir || exit

for name in dir*/image*; do
    num=$(( num + 1 ))
    printf -v newname 'destdir/%.6d.jpg' "$num"
    cp "$name" "$newname"
done
```

Testing:

```
$ tree
.
|-- dir1
|   |-- image1
|   |-- image2
|   |-- image3
|   |-- image4
|   `-- image5
|-- dir2
|   |-- image1
|   |-- image2
|   |-- image3
|   |-- image4
|   `-- image5
|-- dir3
|   |-- image1
|   |-- image2
|   |-- image3
|   |-- image4
|   `-- image5
`-- script

3 directories, 16 files
```

```
$ ./script
```

```
$ tree
.
|-- destdir
|   |-- 000001.jpg
|   |-- 000002.jpg
|   |-- 000003.jpg
|   |-- 000004.jpg
|   |-- 000005.jpg
|   |-- 000006.jpg
|   |-- 000007.jpg
|   |-- 000008.jpg
|   |-- 000009.jpg
|   |-- 000010.jpg
|   |-- 000011.jpg
|   |-- 000012.jpg
|   |-- 000013.jpg
|   |-- 000014.jpg
|   `-- 000015.jpg
|-- dir1
|   |-- image1
|   |-- image2
|   |-- image3
|   |-- image4
|   `-- image5
|-- dir2
|   |-- image1
|   |-- image2
|   |-- image3
|   |-- image4
|   `-- image5
|-- dir3
|   |-- image1
|   |-- image2
|   |-- image3
|   |-- image4
|   `-- image5
`-- script

4 directories, 31 files
```

Always test run things like these on data that is backed up.

Then remove the `dir*` directories if you're happy with the outcome.

Comment: This is just what i wanted. Thanx a lot ! Only when running this i get "newnamecp: cannot create regular file '': No such file or directory". Im running this on a UBUNTU 20.04 desktop.

Comment: @HenrikKjellHolmqvist I'm assuming that you mistyped something relating to setting the `newname` variable or using it. The `printf` command line should look exactly like I show it in my answer, with `printf -v newname` at the start.